# Codeigniter PHP Array Object conversion

Tags: php, json, rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using PHP Codeigniter. I have a result from model as

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [player_id] => 5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [player_id] => 46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729 ) )
```

I want to convert into

```
array("5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572","46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729")
```

I am breaking my head for 2 day on this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure of a CI specific way, but PHP 7+ you should be able to do `array_column($array, "player_id")`

Comment: Use ``typecasting``like this $new_array = (array)$my_objects;

Comment: I have used  `array_column($array, "player_id")`, Where the output is `Array ( [0] => 5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572 [1] => 46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729 )`

Comment: i suspect you get your results from a database ? if you use `$query->result()` you can als use `$query->result_array()`

Comment: Try using json_encode() method to convert it into json format. Also edit your question and add the code you are writing and getting this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_column in PHP 7+ as said by Nigen Sen.

You can also use following function too

```
$players = array_map(function($e) {
    return $e->player_id;
}, $records); // $records is your array object that need to be processed.

print_r( $players );
```

Comment: Thanks Vantiya, as yours and Nigen Sen's suggestion both returns `Array ( [0] => 5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572 [1] => 46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729 )` how to convert again to `array("5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572", "46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729")`

Comment: @StephenPaulraj, do you know that `Array([0] => 'www')` is equal to `Array('www')`?

Comment: It's an array. each elements in array if you declare like array("5bbbdfb4-6986-4383-90af-e3a12782b572", "46834ecd-ceef-49b8-a10a-706ee97ff729") has it's default index starting from zero. It's a characteristics of an array.

Comment: An array is simply a variable that stores data of similar type with index/key.

Comment: @asken-p I do know that, I am passing the same to result to Onesignal i get the error. The acceptable key was `array("x","y","z")`, 'Array('www')' this is not going by.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr_obj), True);
```

also as

```
$arr = (array)$arr_obj;
```